# Migrate data from one mount to another

Tags: linux, azure, rsync, data-migration

In Azure Linux VM we have an LVM that holds the data(1.2TB) of a live application. For some reasons, we want to migrate the data of the application to another LVM and decommission the old one.

We want to achieve this with minimal downtime. What switches/method we can use using rsync to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "LVM"?

Comment: The two LVM on the same VM?

Comment: Yes, both are on same machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you could use [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

The following command could copy one disk to another.

```
rsync -avxHAX --progress /home/test/ /home/back
```

The options are:

```
-a  : all files, with permissions, etc..
-v  : verbose, mention files
-x  : stay on one file system
-H  : preserve hard links (not included with -a)
-A  : preserve ACLs/permissions (not included with -a)
-X  : preserve extended attributes (not included with -a)
```

Also, you could refer to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/307541/copy-entire-file-system-hierarchy-from-one-drive-to-another).

Note: I suggest you could test in your test environment firstly and do in your product environment.

Comment: The mount is live (application using it), would this command work on live mount? And would it resume and copy only delta on second run when application is stopped?

Comment: @A_K Yes, I test in my lab, it works on this scenario. When you rsync, don't need stop your app. But when you modify your app configuration, you need restart it.

Comment: @A_K use rsync,  when you do it second, it is incremental replication.